# Authenticating proxy like CNTLM but without the NTLM

Tags: proxy, proxy-server, http-proxy

On one of the corporate networks I log into, I use CNTLM to centralise my proxy settings.  It's great, because when I have to change my password every so often, I only need to change it in one spot, and everything else works.

On another network I log into, they have a proxy server that isn't using NTLM.  I tried to configure CNTLM to use it, but it doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know of any software like CNTLM that uses non-NTLM auth (basic/digest/etc.) in Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polipo was proposed for non-NTLM auth in this article: http://www.techbite.in/2011/10/setup-transparent-net-access-over-insti.html

Comment: Perhaps you can summarize what the article says, the answer is a bit short now.